# Laravel 5.5 get file after uploading with Storage

Tags: php, laravel, storage, laravel-5.5

In my Laravel 5.5 project I am having a problem in showing uploaded files. I uploaded the files using Storage. The part of store action of the controller is indicated below.

```
        if ($request->hasFile('content_uz'))
        {
            $path = $request->file('content_uz')->store('/content/lesson'.$topic->lesson->id.'/topic'.$topic->id);
            $data->content_uz = $path;
        }
        if ($request->hasFile('content_ru'))
        {
            $path = $request->file('content_ru')->store('/content/lesson'.$topic->lesson->id.'/topic'.$topic->id);
            $data->content_ru = $path;
        }
```

Uploading happened successfully. The path to uploaded 'content_uz' file is stored with "storage/app/content/lesson2/topic3" path and content_uz column is stored in my db as below:

> content\lesson2\topic3\WSjrlG9a1ermGDOvRJTjn9iEIhfFvhVzjaOs6l79.mp4

How can I display the files in my Blade template? I searched the web, but with no result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use method like this,

```
public function showFile() {
    header("Content-type: video/mp4");
    return Storage::get($filePath);
}
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You may access the files of `storage` directory by two ways.

1. If your files are publicly accessible then you may follow [laravel public disk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#the-public-disk).
2. If your files are protected or private then you may declare a route to access the files.

   ```
   Route::get('content/{lesson}/{topic}/{file}', function($lesson, $topic, $file) 
   {
       //Check access logic

       $filePath = '/content/' . $lesson . '/' . $topic . '/' . $file;

       return Storage::get($filePath);
   });
   ```

Comment: do you mean, if my files are not public, I need to open route to call them as src="file_path"   ??